# Convert a text file into columns

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Let's assume I have scientific data, all numbers arranged in a single column but representing an intensities matrix of *n* (width) by *m* (height). The column of the input file has in total *n* * *m* rows. An input example may look like that:

```
1  
2  
3  
......  
30
```

The new output should be such that I have *n* new columns with *m* rows. Sticking to my example with 30 fields input and *n* = 3, *m* = 10, I would need an output file like this (separator does not matter much, could be a blank, a tab etc.):

```
1   11  21  
2   12  22  
... ... ...
10  20  30
```

I use gawk under Windows. Please note that there are no special `FS`, more real-world examples are like 60 * 60 or bigger.

Answer (score 15):

If you are not limited to `awk` but have GNU core-utils *(cygwin, native, ..)* then the simplest solution is to use `pr`:

```
pr -ts" " --columns 3 file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this need solution, perfect with core-utils but the awk solution is more flexible if the number of lines of input does not match n*m output. Still, pleased with a new useful command.

Comment: Identical, but slightly shorter: `pr -3ts" " file`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do:

```
awk '
  { split($0,data); }
  END {
     m = 10;
     n = 3;
     for( i = 1; i<=m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j<n; j++ ) {
            printf "%s ", data[j*m + i] # output data plus space in one line
        }
        # here you might want to start a new line though you did not ask for it:
        printf "\n"; 
     }
  }' inputfile
```

I might have the index counting wrong but I am sure you can figure it out.  The trick is the `split` in the first line.  It splits your input on whitespace and creates an array `data`.  The `END` block runs after processing your file and just accesses `data` by index.  Note array indices count from 0.

Assumption is all data is in a single line.  Your question isn't quite clear on this.  If it is on several lines you'd have to read it into the array differently.

Hope this gets you started.

**EDIT**
I notice you changed your question while I was answering it.  So change

```
{ split($0,data); }
```

to

```
{ data[++i] = $1; }
```

to account for the input being on different lines.  Actually, this would give you the option to read it into a two dimensional array in the first place.

**EDIT 2**

**Read two dimensional array**
To read as a two dimensional array assuming `m` and `n` are known beforehand and not encoded in the input somehow:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
     m = 10;
     n = 3;
  }
  { 
     for( i = 0; i<m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j<n; j++ ) {
            data[i,j] = $0;
        }
     }
     # do something with data
  }' inputfile
```

However, since you only want to reformat your data you could do it immediately. Combining the two solutions getting rid of `data` and passing `m` and `n` on the command line:

```
awk -v m=10 -v n=3'
  { 
     for( i = 0; i<m; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j<n; j++ ) {
            printf "%s ", $0     # output data plus space in one line
        }
        printf "\n";
     }
  }' inputfile
```

Comment: Dear Michael, many thanks for your answer. It works perfect, indexing is spot on. Sorry for late response, i was away over Easter. The trick is really how to read the input. Would you mind to explain your last sentence how to read data in a 2dim array? The data are in just one long single column, indeed (got the formatting wrong in the first instance). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly simple solution (in the example I've set `n` equal to 3; plug in the appropriate value for `n`):

```
awk -v n=3 '{ row = row $1 " "; if (NR % n == 0) { print row; row = "" } }' FILE
```

This works by reading in records one line at a time concatenating each line with the preceding lines. When `n` lines have been concatenated, it prints the concatenated result on a single new line. This repeats until there are no more lines left in the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command

```
paste - - - < input.txt
```

By default, the delimiter is TAB, to change the delimiter, use below command

```
paste - - - -d' ' < input.txt
```