# how to break one column into multiple columns in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I want to break a column into different rows. e.g.,

```
test.dat
1
4
3
4
6
2
4
6
8
```

What I want is to break it into a 3 x 3 matrix

```
out.dat
1   4   4
4   6   6
3   2   8
```

Comment: are you sure your answer is correct? I mean how is your output coming? Is there any mathematical calculation or just take three like and make it in a row?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I miss typed the output. Kindly check the new one, I have edited..

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687670/split-a-column-in-multiple-columns

Comment: As the accepted answer has nothing to do with `awk`, this question is apparently no duplicate to "[Convert a text file into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687670/convert-a-text-file-into-columns)", which specifically asks for a solution in `awk` (under Windows!) only!  So the questions (both) might be asked poorly, but they are no duplicates for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using:

```
pr -ts" " --columns 3 file_name
```

It is good and short if you don't want to use `awk`.

There are other methods too (one I told you, I also learnt it from there):

[Convert text file into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687670/convert-text-file-into-columns)

Comment: `-w180` if you are getting truncation of each column to fit the output into the default 80 character width.

Comment: There are tons of other ways to do it under Linux, but as this Linux question is foolishly marked as duplicate for a Windows-only-question, I am prohibited to add some other ways on how to archive the desired effect.  **Sorry SO, you failed miserably!**