# How do I turn a text file with a single column into a matrix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, text, awk

I have a text file that has a single column of numbers, like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to convert it into two columns, in the left to right order this way:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I can do it with:

```
awk '{print>"line-"NR%2}' file
paste line-0  line-1 >newfile
```

But I think the reliance on two intermediate files will make it fragile in a script.

I'd like to use something like `cat file | mystery-zip-command >newfile`

Comment: see also second half of this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308654/109046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`paste`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) to do this:

```
paste -d " " - - < file > newfile
```

---

You can also use [`pr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pr):

```
pr -ats" " -2 file > newfile
```

- `-a`     - use round robin order
- `-t`     - suppress header and trailer
- `-s " "` - use single space as the delimiter
- `-2`     - two column output

---

See also:

- [Convert a text file into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687670/convert-a-text-file-into-columns)

Comment: I want to accept the answer with 'paste', can you separate it out?

Comment: Just put the `paste` based answer at the front.

Answer (score 3):

another alternative

```
$ seq 6 | xargs -n2

1 2
3 4
5 6
```

or with `awk`

```
$ seq 6 | awk '{ORS=NR%2?FS:RS}1'

1 2
3 4
5 6
```

if you want the output terminate with a new line in case of odd number of input lines..

```
$ seq 7 | awk '{ORS=NR%2?FS:RS}1; END{ORS=NR%2?RS:FS; print ""}'

1 2
3 4
5 6
7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { printf("%s", $1) }
     NR % 2 == 0 { printf(" %s\n", $1) }
     END { if (NR % 2 == 1) print "" }' file
```

The odd lines are printed with no newline after them, to print the first column. The even lines are printed with a space first and a newline after, to print the second column. At the end, if there were an odd number of lines, we print a newline so we don't end in the middle of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{print ( ((getline nl) > 0)? $0" "nl : $0 )}' file
```

The output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

---

- `(getline nl)>0` - `getline` will get the next record and assign it to variable `nl`. The *getline* command returns `1` if it finds a record and `0` if it encounters the end of the file

---

Short *GNU* ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file
```

- `N` - add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space
- `s/\n/ /` - replace newline with whitespace within captured pattern space

Comment: @EdMorton, not both, sed approach works fine on sequence `1
2
3
4
5
6
7
`. As for awk approach - I've extended it for odd sequences

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while IFS= read -r odd; do IFS= read -r even; echo "$odd $even"; done < file
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: @EdMorton: I came up with a bash solution because the question is tagged with bash and there are already multiple answers with awk. John has now the choice between very different solutions. Okay, this bash solution is not performant and is not really scalable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 6 | awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}'
1 2
3 4
5 6
$
$ seq 7 | awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7
$
```

Note that it always adds a terminating newline - that is important as future commands might depend on it, e.g.:

```
$ seq 6 | awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS); print}' | wc -l
       3
$ seq 7 | awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS); print}' | wc -l
       3
$ seq 7 | awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}' | wc -l
       4
```

Just change the single occurrence of `2` to `3` or however many columns you want if your requirements change:

```
$ seq 6 | awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}'
1 2 3
4 5 6
$ seq 7 | awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}'
1 2 3
4 5 6
7
$ seq 8 | awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}'
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8
$ seq 9 | awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print} END{if (ORS==FS) printf RS}'
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq 6 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -r 's/([^ ]* [^ ]* )/\1\n/g'
```