# Concatenate strings from one text file and storing it in variable using bash command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have 500 plus user name in text file, each names are in different rows, I want to read it in batches of 10 names and store it in a new text file.

Input:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
Name6
Name7
Name8
Name9
Name10
Name11
Name22
Name13
Name14
Name15
Name16
Name17
Name18
Name19
Name20
```

Output:

```
Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8,Name9,Name10
Name11,Name12,Name13,Name14,Name15,Name16,Name17,Name18,Name19,Name20
```

I have attached the input text contains my original data and I have also attached the format of output I am expecting.

Can someone help?

Comment: Then please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn a text file with a single column into a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185052/how-do-i-turn-a-text-file-with-a-single-column-into-a-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '{u = u s $0; s=","} !(NR%10){print u; u = s = ""}' file
```

or this:

```
awk '{ORS=RS} NR%10{ORS=","}1' file
```